# Cancelling a logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I was wondering if there was a way to cancel out a logarithm?
For example:

$\log_a A$ > $\log_a B$

What would a have to be for the log to go away and be left with A > B?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything is positive here, and $a\ne1$, the answer is:

- If $a>1$, then $\log_a b <\log_ac\iff b<c$
- If $0<a<1$, then $\log_ab<\log_ac\iff c<b$

Comment: Ty for the answer and correction! ;)

Answer (score 1):

As long as $A, B >0$, if $\log_a(A)>log_a(B)$, then $A>B$ since logarithmic functions are $increasing$ as long as $a>1$, i.e. if $a>b$, $\log(a)>\log(b)$

$A, B>0$ is necessary since otherwise $\log(A)$ (or B) isn't defined.

Comment: @Joanpemo Thanks for the correction, didn't think through that quite enough.